# Setup a java servlet and an Ajax request to get a JPG image to the front end

Tags: java, ajax, image, servlets, send

[Picture of response "text"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9DG8.jpg) It seems simple! (Or should be) Based on user data send an Ajax request and see if there's an image stored for this user. If there is, send it back and load it on the page. I have seen a lot of code for either ajax or the servlet itself, but nothing together.

Here is my js ajax call:

```
function getImage(page){
    //var page = new Image();
    $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"GetImageServlet",
    data: {
        bookIDIn: currentBook.id,
        userIDIn: currentBook.ownerID,
        pageIn: page
    },
    async:true,
    success:function(resp){
        if(resp == "false"){
            document.getElementById("serverErrorCode").innerHTML = "101_GETIMAGE_ERR";
            showErrorModal();
        } else {
            //HOW TO TURN resp INTO AN IMAGE?
        }
    },
    error:function(){
        document.getElementById("serverErrorCode").innerHTML = "102_GETIMAGE_ERR";
        showErrorModal();
    }
    });
```

}

Here is the servlet:

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String ownerID = request.getParameter("userIDIn");
    String bookID = request.getParameter("bookIDIn");
    String page = request.getParameter("pageIn");

    boolean resp = ownerID != null && bookID != null && page != null;
    if(resp){
        resp = !ownerID.isEmpty() && !bookID.isEmpty() && !page.isEmpty();
    }
    if(resp){
        String root = baseRoot + ownerID + "\\" + bookID + "\\page\\p" + page + ".jpg";
        System.out.println("root: " + root);
        ServletContext cntx = request.getServletContext();
        String mime = cntx.getMimeType(root);
        if (mime == null) {
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
          return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("mime: " + mime);
        }

        response.setContentType(mime);
        File file = new File(root);
        response.setContentLength((int)file.length());

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

         byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
         int count = 0;
         while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
           out.write(buf, 0, count);
        }
      out.close();
      in.close();
    } else {
        response.getWriter().print(resp);
    }



}
```

This servlet works in that it gets data back to the user, just don't know exactly how to turn it into the img element that I need. Not sure if the servlet needs to be changed or not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting some error ,exactly what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to turn the bytes(I assume what I have is an array of bytes) into image data. I have seen code like this:

Comment: document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," + YourByte;

Comment: but it doesn't work for me

Comment: for a start you should be using a `GET`

Comment: var base64String = btoa(resp.Image);
            $("#imgFromScript").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," +  base64String);   try once. use your document.getElementById("ItemPreview") to refre, what id you given to image

Comment: Thanks that seems like on the right track but still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you doing this for an assignment where you've been instructed to use `Servlet` manually?

Comment: Not for an assignment, haven't been instructed to use a servlet manually.

Comment: document.getElementById("ItemPreview").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + response.ImageBytesAsString); have you tried like this.

Comment: Is this problem I using a jpg file format?

Comment: @rishabhkeshari123 using response.ImageBytesAsString shows up as undefined

Comment: try this jsp fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/99jAX/1/

Answer (score 0):

jpg may be the problem.you can use multiple content type also.

data:image/jpg;image/gif;image/png;image/jpeg;base64,

try once...